# Application of Rouché's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis II, and I have a question about the proof proposition 1.1, chapter 8. Here is the proposition:

> (assume $U, V \subset \mathbb{C}$ open) If $f:U\to V$ is holomorphic and injective, then $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U$. In particular, the inverse of $f$ defined on its range is holomorphic, and thus the inverse of a conformal map is also holomorphic.

Here is the begining of the proof:

*We argue by contradiction, and suppose that $f'(z_0) = 0$ for some $z_0 \in U$. Then*

$$f(z) − f(z_0) = a(z − z_0)^k + G(z) \text{ for all } z \text{ near } z_0,$$

*with $a \neq 0$, $k \geq 2$ and $G$ vanishing to order $k + 1$ at $z_0$. For sufficiently small $w$, we write*

$$f(z) − f(z_0) − w = F(z) + G(z), \text{ where } F(z) = a(z − z_0)^k − w.$$

*Since $|G(z)| < |F(z)|$ on a small circle centered at $z_0$, and $F$ has at
least two zeros inside that circle, Rouche’s theorem implies that $f(z) −
f(z_0) − w$ has at least two zeros there. [...]*

I understand that, for a fixed $w$, we have $|G(z)| < |F(z)|$ on a circle $\partial B_r(z_0)$ with small enough $r>0$. But I really don't know how can we be sure that $F$ has at least two roots inside this ball, since the values of $r$ and $w$ seem to be interdependent.

How can I make sense out of this?

Comment: $F(z) =  (z-z_0)^k- w/a$ has at least $k$ zeros on the **disk** $|z-z_0| < r$  iff $|w / a| < r$

Comment: what you're saying is: just take $w$ with $|w/a|<r$. But haven't we fixed $w$ already before we chose $r$? I mean, if we changed $w$ we would also be affecting $r$...

Comment: just take $|w| > 0$ as small as you want and $< |a|$ (For sufficiently small w) and $r = 2 |w/a|^{1/k}$ (I forgot the ${}^{1/k}$)

Comment: Ok, let's take $w$ exactly like you said. I agree this garantees that $F$ has at least 2 roots in $B_r(z_0)$. But how do you know $|G(z)|<|F(z)|$ on $\partial B_r(z_0)$?

Comment: because $G(z)$ is $\mathcal{O}(|z-z_0|^{k+1})$ so the more $|z-z_0|$ is small, the more $\frac{|G(z)|}{|F(z)|} \to 0$

Comment: (don't know how it is written in your book, but here $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n = f(z_0) + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n = f(z_0) + a(z-z_0)^k + G(z)$ with $a = \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} $ the first non-zero non-constant term and $G(z) =\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n =\mathcal{O}(|z-z_0|^{k+1}) $ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $\frac{G(z)}{a(z-z_0)^k}$ has no singularity in $z_0$, and instead has a root there. Thus there is a radius $r$ around $z_0$ such that this fraction has an absolute value smaller $\frac12$ for $|z-z_0|\le r$. This determines a (maximal) value of $r$ independent of any $w$. Now
$$
|G(z)|<\frac12|a(z-z_0)^k|,
$$
and if likewise
$$
|w|<\frac12|a|r^k
$$
then for all $|z-z_0|=r$
$$
|F(z)|\ge|a(z-z_0)^k|-|w|>\frac12|a|r^k>|G(z)|.
$$